# How to port a Python program to Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I'm trying to port a Python program to Ruby but I'm completely ignorant about Python.

Could you give me any advice?

I want to run `sampletrain` method. However, I dont understand why `features=self.getfeatures(item)` is available. `getfeatures` is just an instance variable, isn't it? It seem to be used as a method.

[docclass.py](http://code.google.com/p/bnxmlclassifier/source/browse/trunk/FeedReader/docclass.py?r=18#15):

```
class classifier:
  def __init__(self,getfeatures,filename=None):
    # Counts of feature/category combinations
    self.fc={}
    # Counts of documents in each category
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures

  def train(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Increment the count for every feature with this category
    for f in features:
      self.incf(f,cat)

    # Increment the count for this category
    self.incc(cat)
    self.con.commit()

  def sampletrain(cl):
    cl.train('Nobody owns the water.','good')
    cl.train('the quick rabbit jumps fences','good')
    cl.train('buy pharmaceuticals now','bad')
    cl.train('make quick money at the online casino','bad')
    cl.train('the quick brown fox jumps','good')
```

Comment: Here's a guess: perhaps the second argument passed in during initialization is a a function; though it's assigned to a property during initialization, it can be invoked later on with parens. (This is similar to JavaScript, but not Python.)

Comment: @ThiefMaster and steenslag :) just to work.. thanks your nice comments.

Comment: @Phrogz 'similar to JS' is easy to understand for me. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, because the brackets for a method call aren't optional it is possible to distinguish between a reference to a method and an invocation of a method. i.e.

```
def example():
    pass

x = example # x is now a reference to the example 
            # method. no invocation takes place
            # but later the method can be called as
            # x()
```

vs.

```
x = example() # calls example and assigns the return value to x
```

Because the brackets for a method call are optional in Ruby you need to use some extra code e.g. `x = method(:example)` and `x.call` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You should be able to use either the style I've given above or write `initialize` to accept a block as suggested by tokland depending on whether you're likely to want to provide a named method or an anonymous block for the `getfeatures` functionality. If you need any more details, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to send *behaviours* in Ruby (since `getfeatures` in your code is clearly a callable) is to use blocks:

```
class Classifier
  def initialize(filename = nil, &getfeatures)
    @getfeatures = getfeatures
    ...
  end

  def train(item, cat)
    features = @getfeatures.call(item)
    ...
  end

  ...
end

Classifier.new("my_filename") do |item|
  # use item to build the features (an enumerable, array probably) and return them
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're translating from Python, you'll have to learn Python so you're *not* "completely ignorant" about it. No short cuts.